# Assertion error with empty route in Angular 9

Tags: angular, routes, angular9

I have following router configuration in my module:

```
const publicRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'public',
    component: PublicComponent,
    children: [
      {path: 'sign', component: SignComponent},
      {path: '', redirectTo: '/public/sign', pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: '**', redirectTo: 'sign'},
    ]
  },
];
```

But when I navigate to only /public I am not redirected, but I get `ERROR Error: ASSERTION ERROR: Type passed in is not ComponentType, it does not have 'ɵcmp' property.`
Can you bring a bit of light to my life please? I am horribly lost.

Comment: try `{path: '', redirectTo: 'sign', pathMatch: 'full'}`

Comment: @Raiper34 how did you resolved this error?

Answer (score 2):

When this happened to me, the issue was that one of my routes was directing to a non-component class (with a similar name to the component class I wanted to direct to, I just fat-fingered the import). Posting this here hoping it helps someone else if you face this as I scratched my head for a while on a pretty simple fix.

Answer (score 0):

```
const publicRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'public',
    component: PublicComponent,
    children: [
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'sign', pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: 'sign', component: SignComponent},
      {path: '**', redirectTo: 'sign'}
    ]
  },
];
```

Comment: Could you add what problem you solve, and short description?

Comment: soln for @Raiper34 question

Comment: Ok, we know, but what causes the problem and why?